# Mapping different users to folders with mod_rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite

I'm setting up a DAV server with Apache 2.2 and would like, if at all possible, to be able to redirect a user to their own folder without having per-user URLs, if at all possible.

So I point a user to `https://dav.example.org/`, I have authentication enabled (AuthType Digest, AuthDigestProvider file) so the user logs in, and then content is served from `/home/%{REMOTE_USER}/dav`.

Or that's the theory anyway. The problem is I can't get it to work. The basic rule (at least to start with - I know this won't necessarily redirect everything, but if I can get the root folder to work and at least get an index of files, I can tweak the reg-ex later):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{LA-U:REMOTE_USER} (.*)
RewriteRule ^/        /home/%1/dav/
```

The problem is that the lookahead doesn't seem to work - it always returns an empty string (I'm running with `RewriteLogLevel 5`, and get "`RewriteCond: input='' pattern='(.*)' => matched`" in the log). I know I'm logged in with a username as I can see the user in the appropriate field in access_log.

I've also tried moving this into .htaccess, but it didn't seem to play there (the rewrite engine didn't seem to even start); similarly, it didn't play under a  config in the main config file (again, it looked like it failed to process any of the rules).

I had some success with it under  in that the remote-user was successfully mapped, but then it got stuck in a recursive loop (error log tells me "*Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary.*", and then I read in the manual that  wasn't really supported anyway[1], so I'm rejecting that path.

It looks like what I'm doing *should* be straightforward, but I'm failing to see what I'm missing.

Trying to keep config/log snippets brief here to keep question tidy - can add snippets on request.

[1] The manual for mod_rewrite in 2.2 says "Although rewrite rules are syntactically permitted in  and  sections, this should never be necessary and is unsupported."

---

**EDIT** ... this is the virtual site config (I've got a number of virtual sites, so I'm assuming that the root httpd.conf isn't needed)

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol -ALL +TLSv1
    SSLCertificateFile <edited out>
    SSLCertificateKeyFile <edited out>
    SSLCACertificateFile <edited out>
    SSLCertificateChainFile <edited out>
    SSLHonorCipherOrder On
    SSLCipherSuite RC4-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA

    ServerAdmin admin@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/dav.example.org
    ServerName dav.example.org
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/dav.example.org.errlog
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/dav.example.org.log combined
    RewriteLog /var/log/apache2/dav.example.org.rewritelog
    RewriteLogLevel 5
    LogLevel debug

    <Location />
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
            Dav On

            AuthName DAV
            AuthType Digest
            AuthDigestProvider file
            AuthUserFile /tmp/dig

            <LimitExcept OPTIONS>
                    # Testing only - running single-user
                    Require user cej
            </LimitExcept>
    </Location>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{LA-U:REMOTE_USER} (.*)
    RewriteRule ^/        /home/%1/dav/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Please provide httpd.conf

Comment: @bybe -- vhost config added

Comment: Does the Apache service have permission to read within the user groups home folders?

Comment: Yes. Originally this was configured with a hard-coded path (i.e., DocumentRoot was pointing at /home/<whatever>/dav), and that worked swimmingly. I'm now just trying to make the physical location for this dynamic on the username.

I guess an alternative approach would be so that someone pointed to `https://dav.example.org/<user>/` and there's a RewriteCond to make sure the <user> portion of the URL matches %{REMOTE_USER} and thus redirects accordingly, but I still have the problem that %{REMOTE_USER} and %{LA-U:REMOTE_USER} don't seem to get expanded (so again the condition can't be checked).